# Determining the conditionality of a problem of evaluating a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

I have a problem of evaluating the following function. $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=(\ln\frac{1}{x})^{-\frac{1}{7}}$ if $0<x<1$. The problem is to determine if this problem is ill or well conditioned.

I wanted to use the modulus of continuity which is defined as $w(\delta)=\sup|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$ where $|x_1-x_2|\le \delta$. And conditionality is determined by $\frac{w(\delta)}{\delta}$.

The supremum of $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$, by my calculation turns out to be $\infty$ which I'm not sure if it's correct. So how do I determine if this problem of evaluating the function is ill or well conditioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $0<x<1$ we have $ \ln x <0$, thus

$f(x)= \frac{1}{(- \ln x)^{1/7}}.$

For $x \to 0+$, we have $(- \ln x)^{1/7} \to \infty,$ thus $f(x) \to 0 =f(0).$

This shows that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1).$